# bootstrap adds a semi-tranparent layer to my background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a form on my page with bootstrap css.
I use an image as background which covers the entire background. 
bootstrap seems to add a semi-tranparency to the top of my page, which disappears when scrolling the page: http://www.landoflove.be/medewerkers.php and I can't seem to find out why it's doing that. It does the same thing on the main page landoflove.be .Why is this happening and how can I disable it?

Comment: What help your expecting without a code? add the code here! before asking check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is invalid. There's no doctype and you have unclosed div somewhere. Fix this first, then add:

```
html, body {padding:0; margin:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this CSS in your landoflove.css file

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/bgoff-min.png) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: baloo paaji, sans-serif;
}
```

The problem is here

```
background: url(../img/bgoff-min.png) no-repeat center fixed;
```

Your image is having the size of 1227 X 1159 pixels. and you have added **no-repeat center fixed**
if you remove that you will have the background to be stretched something like this [image: -+]

Also, you need to modify the **HTML**

Seems that you are using only one

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

and all your form elements are inside this which is not a right approach.So suggesting you to have one form-group in one row

Answer (score 0):

the mark-up was indeed invalid for some tags because is was a work in progress. 
I seem to have found what my particular problem was:
    body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/bgoff-min.png) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: baloo paaji, sans-serif;
    }
The height: 100% caused the problem. Now the transparent layer is indeed gone, but i still have no clue why it added such tranparency in the first place.